# Semantic ui modal won't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui, and want to load some remote content from another page through ajax. I can get the modal to populate, but when it opens, it won't scroll.

I have observeChanges set to true, and am even calling the .modal('refresh').

Code snippets below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Javascript**

```
$('.ui.modal')
  .modal({
    observeChanges: true
  })
;

$('#link')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var modal = $('#modal');

    var content = modal.find('.content');
    $.get("/page", function(data) {
      content.append($('.column', data));
      modal
        .modal('refresh')
        .modal('show')
      ;
    });
  })
;
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="/page" id="link">open modal</a>


<div id="modal" class="ui long modal">
  <div class="header">
    Page
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

**Javascript**

```
$('.ui.long.modal')
  .modal({
    observeChanges: true
  })
;

$('#link')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var modal = $('#modal');

    var content = modal.find('.content');
    $.get("/page", function(data) {
      content.append($('.column', data));
      modal.({observeChanges: true})
        .modal('refresh')
        .modal('show')
      ;
    });
  })
;
```